# In Freemarker Change output date format irrespective of input format

Tags: freemarker

```
${(.vars["OCRResponse"].Date)?datetime("ANY RANDOM FORMAT")?string("mm-dd-yy").
```

Can we use `If Else` within `?datetime`, or can we resolve this by using switch case?

Comment: As it's not an answer, just as a comment.... `(.vars["OCRResponse"].Date)` can be simply written as `OCRResponse.Date`

Answer (score 1):

If that date format is quite "random", and you need to do this a lot, then you are probably better of writing a `freemarker.core.TemplateDateFormat`+`TemplateDateFormatFactory` implementation, do the complex date parsing logic in Java, then register the factory as a "custom date format" (that's a FreeMarker configuration setting), let's say with name `"random"`. Then you can do `${OCRResponse.Date?date.@random?string('MM-dd-yy')}`. If you set the `date_format` configuration setting to `MM-dd-yy`, then you can even just write `${OCRResponse.Date?date.@random}`.

You can find concrete examples of defining a custom formats here: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_custom_formats.html

Another possibility is to use `#if`/`#elseif`/`#else` of course. If you need to do that on multiple places, then put your parser logic into a `#function`, where you `#return` the parsed date. So where you insert a date you just have something like `${parseRandom(OCRResponse.Date)}` (here I have assumed that `date_format` is `MM-dd-yy`, otherwise add `?string('MM-dd-yy')`).